# Get raster data by coordinate

Tags: raster, javascript, geojson, json

I do have some data from raster files (timelines, 30m) which I would like to access by coordinate from a web interface. E.g. I know the coordinate and need the data from the corresponding raster file. I do NOT want to load the data in a PostGIS database.

I thought about dumping the data in JSON files (similar to raster image tiles) on a storage and then load the according file to the coordinate I have, similar to WMS tiles. But I am struggling to figure out a way how to "map" the coordinate to the right raster tile and what would be proper folder structure?

Is there any algorithm for this?